# Why does this code that attempts to update a pandas column with a comparison, not work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

So the `label` column is `'SARCASM'` or `'NOT_SARCASM'`.

I'm able to iterate through the column like this:

```
for v in df['label']:
    if v == 'SARCASM':
        v = 1
    else:
        v = 0
```

but the assignments `v=1` and `v=0` don't update that col entry. The `if v =='SARCASM'` appears to be working as I can make it print something else, but the `v=1` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Welcome to SO. [You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on the big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can also upvote answers by clicking on the upper gray triangle.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354584/teaching-new-users-how-to-accept-an-answer) As of now [you've only accepted an answer on 1 of 7 of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12439213/ajt)

Answer (score 1):

Because `v` is only a local variable (within your for-loop iteration), so you're only overwriting it, not that column. (The dataframe doesn't know anything about `'v'`.)

**You want to assign to the column `df['label']` itself.** In this case you can get away with a direct string comparison, which gives a boolean, and convert that to an int (1/0):

```
df['label'] = (df['label'] == 'SARCASM').astype(int)
```

or for a more general mapping of multiple strings to (integer) values:

```
df['label'] = map({'SARCASM': 1, 'NOT_SARCASM': 0, 'SOMETHING_ELSE': 2})
```

(By the way, you can avoid almost all iteration over a dataframe by instead using
`df['col'].apply()`, `df['col'].map()` etc. See the [pandas User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html).)

Answer (score 1):

You can use map method for transformation.

```
map_val = {'SARCASM':1, 'NOT_SARCASM':0}
df['label'] = df['label'].map(map_val)
```

Comment: Wow like magic. Thanks so much, i'll read the map function carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
df['label'] = (df['label'] == 'SARCASM').astype(int)
```

As for why your code doesn't work, I believe when you loop over `df['label']`, you actually loop over a copy of the data, e.g. you don't get to modify the element of the series inside the loop.